# Python Regex not matching all strings

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, lxml

So I am trying to match monetary strings in item pages on amazon using Python and regex.

My current code as it stands:

```
import csv
import requests as rq
import re
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

i = 0
urls = csv.reader(open('/Users/Fuck/Documents/Amazon/HTML_Parsetest/urls.csv'))
for url in urls:
    r=rq.get(url[0],stream=True)
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=2048):
        if chunk:
            data = chunk
            soup=bs(data, "lxml")
            elem=soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'a-text-right dp-used-col'})
            print(elem)
            if elem!=[]:
                i = i + 1
                s=re.findall('(\£\d+\.\d+)+',str(elem[0]))
                print (i,"Price:", s[0].split()[0])
```

The current print out from the [first url](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0198596790/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=1HSJVRP8R6QX2T0R7FYV&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=577047927&pf_rd_i=desktop):

```
[<td class="a-text-right dp-used-col">
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/offer-listing/019859660X/ref=tmm_hrd_used_olp_0?ie=UTF8&amp;condition=used&amp;qid=&amp;sr=">
<span>£51.70</span>
</a>
</td>]
1 Price: £51.70
[<td class="a-text-right dp-used-col">
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/offer-listing/0198596790/ref=tmm_pap_used_olp_sr?ie=UTF8&amp;condition=used&amp;qid=&amp;sr=">
<span>£35.15</span>
</a>
</td>]
2 Price: £35.15
```

The print out from the [second url](http://www.amazon.co.uk/A-First-Course-Fluid-Dynamics/dp/0521274249/ref=pd_sim_14_1?ie=UTF8&dpID=41VTJsnF5jL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR107%2C160_&refRID=0ASXTXN08WE9R18TJ48X):

```
[<td class="a-text-right dp-used-col">
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/offer-listing/0521254167/ref=tmm_hrd_used_olp_0?ie=UTF8&amp;condition=used&amp;qid=&amp;sr=">
<span>£355.37</span>
</a>
</td>, <td class="a-text-right dp-used-col">
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/offer-listing/0521274249/ref=tmm_pap_used_olp_sr?ie=UTF8&amp;condition=used&amp;qid=&amp;sr=">
<span>£29.93</span>
</a>
</td>]
3 Price: £355.37
```

In the second url run, it finds the whole td block as one entity whereas in the first it finds them as separate blocks and I cannot work out why. 
So it seems my regex will only find one instance of the string in each block.

How do I get it to find both strings £355.37 and £29.93 in the second url?

Comment: I find that the [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) is usually helpful

Comment: @miraculixx The regular expression appears to be fine.

Comment: Does the price always comes in `£` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `iter_content()` here, since that means you're parsing parts of HTML instead of entire documents. BeautifulSoup might manage to extract some stuff anyways, but you'll be missing a lot of content without knowing.

Beyond that, you're already using `soup.findall()` and `re.finall()` when searching, but you're only looking at the first match from each. Iterate over the results of both of these and you should see all of the results.

Of course, there could be many other issues. For example, the price could be not written in the HTML at all, or not written in exactly the format you are searching for, or not found in the tags you are searching through...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
s=re.findall('(\£\d+\.\d+)+',str(elem[0]))
```

This returns a list of strings which you can iterate so `s[1]` should have the 2nd price.

I don't think parsing the raw html is a good idea for extracting those prices though, Amazon may decide to change the html/css/js at any time and the code will break. You should take a look at their web service:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm currently looking into using boto as it could be much easier than this is.